# Banco sqlite fechado quando consulta

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Boa tarde, estou fazendo uma aplicação android, estou com alguns problemas com o banco. Quando roda no emulador ele chama o activity do vendador depois de salvo, ele chama o login, no login tem um método getConfiguracao() é no método de configuração que o erro ocorre ao abrir o banco, todos os métodos das classes DAO tem a mesma estrutura do VendedorDao. Alguém o que estou fazendo de errado!!

```
public void salvarVendedor(Vendedor vendedor){
    bancoDados.escrever().beginTransaction();
    try {
        values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("id_vendedor",vendedor.getIdVendedor());
        values.put("login",vendedor.getLogin());
        values.put("senha",vendedor.getSenha());
        values.put("desconto",vendedor.getDesconto());
        values.put("mac",vendedor.getMac());
        values.put("inativo", vendedor.getInativo());
        values.put("valor_verba", vendedor.getValorVerba());

        bancoDados.escrever().insert("TB_VENDEDORES",null,values);
        bancoDados.escrever().setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (SQLiteException e){
        Log.i("Erro ","salvar vendedor" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        bancoDados.escrever().endTransaction();
        bancoDados.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Beleza? Qual o erro que você está recebendo?

Comment: da o endereco do banco na pasta Data e  diz que esta fechado Database is closed

Comment: Entendi, em qual método você abre a conexão com o banco?

Comment: no login tem o getConfiguracao() para verificar algumas coisa antes de logar, ai onde tem o erro.